# Which Java XSLT Processor can I use that supports IBM Datapower extensions?

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

I am very new to all XML related technologies and barely know anything about them.

Currently, the simulators I have to develop for that are provided by IBM. I have to replace their functionality with in house system. What I basically have to do it perform transformations on several XMLs based on XSLT files that uses IBM Datapower extensions. (dp:url-open, dp:priority, dp:set-variable et cetera).

I have tried using Xalan and Saxon. I do not believe they support IBM DP extensions. The errors I get(unknown extension instruction) are always on the tags which uses DataPower functions.

On top of that, there are several XSLT files that has exclude-result-payload-prefixes in stylesheet part on which I can barely find any information.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config"
extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-payload-prefixes="dp dpconfig">
```

I am not sure which is the way to go here. Or whether this is even possible without incorporating services from IBM. My question is, can I use IBM Datapower extensions with just including the namespace for it? If so, which XSLT processor would you prefer?

Comment: The only XSLT processor that supports IBM Datapower extensions (with a `dp:` prefix) is IBM Datapower.

Comment: Alright good to know. Now that I know using dp is not possible without using Datapower's processor, I will find alternative ways to implement same functionality without using dp extensions. Thanks.